# How can I check the settings in hive CLI?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I want to run a hive query in hive command and I want to make it faster, so I ran:

```
hive:messages> set mapred.job.priority = VERY_HIGH; hive:messages> set
hi = 1;
```

but I found actually I can set any string to be anything in hive so I wonder is there a way to check all the settings I have made?

Answer (score 21):

To list all the settings available in the current Hive session,

```
hive> SET;
```

This will list all the

- System Variables
- Environment Variables
- Hadoop, Hive Configurations (User defined and Default properties)
- Hive Variables set using `set`, `define`, `hivevar`.

It is not possible to filter only a specific set of variables. But to get the value of a particular configuration/variable, use the configuration name as the argument to `SET`

```
hive> SET zzzz=123;
hive> SET zzzz;
zzzz=123;
```

Comment: Can I do a filtration like "grep" to specify a parameter?

Comment: No, not within the hive shell. You can do `hive -e "SET;" | grep <Search-String>`