# getting hive configuration from the command line

Tags: hadoop, hive

I wish to retrieve hive configurations from the command line.
Is there any utility like hadoop getconf -confKey  for Hive?

i.e.: I wish to retrieve the warehouse dir from hive.xml, get the value and then exit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `set` command, which will print out the current configuration if not provided a value for the key

```
hive -e 'set hive.metastore.warehouse.dir;'
```

Comment: Hi Cricket, thanks for your quick response, but I am looking for get rather than a set. something on the lines of hadoop getconf -confkey. hive -e "set ... " will start a hive shell, which I am not interested in. I just need the configuration. Thanks for your time though.

Comment: Sounds like you're not trying this. That's what this does. If you don't give a value, it'll print out the current one

Comment: You cannot get a hive-site.xml value through the Hadoop CLI utility. If you really want to, you can parse the xml manually, but that'll miss all the default values

Comment: Oh.. Got that.. 

Comment: The hive -e approach works, but takes a lot of time. What I need is just to parse the xml and spit out the config. But now, i am unnecessary creating the hive cli instance on my machine. Wished it could have been a bit simpler. Again, thanks

Comment: Well, even running `hadoop getconf` starts up a JVM, so it's a necessary evil

Comment: Besides, the Hive client doesn't need to know about the metastore, for example. Only HiveServer2 does. Therefore I believe that connection is needed

Answer (score 0):

In continuation to what [@OneCricketeer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2308683/onecricketeer) gave, once inside the beeline shell, we can issue below-set command to find out what is the value of a given parameter.

> set hive.metastore.warehouse.dir;

To list out all the settings we can issue just set as below

> set;

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42239769/5927843